# How to insert data in Windows Form Application using c# in VS 2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, ado.net, sql-server-express

I have been trying to insert Data in my Local Database Table using c# in Visual Studio 2013 since long but not able to succeed. What is the role of Data Dictionary? I am getting an exception

> a first chance exception of type 'system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception' occurred in system.data.dll

The Code is :

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Integrated Security=true;
User Instance=true;AttachDBFilename=C:\Users\User_name\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\DataB.mdf;");

                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Table(Id,FirstName, LastName) VALUES(1,'xyz','abc')",conn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch(Exception ee)
            {
                Console.Write("Exception");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a good chance that your table is not actually named "Table".  or is it?

Comment: import at the top  `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException`

Comment: Exception is thrown at this line
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Answer (score -1):

Is C drive your OS drive? If so , sometimes the application must run as Administrator. Or move your database file to another location then C, then try it.

Comment: Should I move entire project or only .mdf file to other drive?

Comment: Just the database file. Don't  forget to change the path in connection string.